# Ошибка при вызове функции .replace Android " wrong second argument type"

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
        item.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
```

Не принимает второй аргумент (fragment), нашел обсуждение на английском Stackoverflow, но всёравно не понял как правильно исправить ситуацию. 
Вот ссылка на [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878779/adding-a-fragment-a-wrong-second-argument-type-error-occurs), объясните как исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей ссылке написано, что проблема в том, что фрагмент унаследуется от класса `android.app.Fragment`, а метод `replace` принимает в качестве второго параметра `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

**P.S.** Если сильные проблемы с английским, то можно попробовать переводчик от Google.

Comment: Я понял перевод, но не понял как исправить проблему

Comment: @Opimand, у вас фрагмент, который вы хотите отобразить от какого класса наследуется?

Comment: extends Fragment  
из пакета 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: @Opimand, ну если это точно так, то решение по вашей ссылке не подходит. Потому что там проблема была в том, что фрагмент был унаследован от android.app.Fragment